# Count of fields code works in one server and does not work in another server

Tags: php

I am trying to select fields with a condition and display their counts. The counts display in one server while the same code does not display ANY counts ($num01 and $rowno)in another server. Both servers have same PHP version (5.6) and same database structure. Please guide.

Following is my code -

```
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
$sql="select num, ode_y from Topics order by num asc";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$sql1="SELECT * from Topics ORDER BY num ASC";
$result1=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
$rowno = mysqli_num_rows($result1);

<span>Total $rowno registered 
topics</span>

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    $odey1= ($row['ode_y']);

    $sql01="SELECT ode  
            from fltr2 AS s 
                INNER JOIN Register AS r ON s.sender=r.sender 
                            and r.reg=0 
                            and s.ode='$odey1'";

    $result01 = mysqli_query($con,$sql01);
    $num01=mysqli_num_rows($result01);

 <div>Counts : ".$num01."</a>
 </div>
}
```

Comment: The display count is different because the numbers of rows in the tables on the different servers/databases are different and/or the row values are different.

Comment: In the second server, it does not display any counts at all

Comment: Please check the display of error messages, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=1

Comment: Checked. No error messages

Comment: Then check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death why nothing is displayed at all.

Comment: @Progman This does not solve problem